# Perl Inline::C return pdl or 0 on failure

Tags: perl, return-type, pdl, inline-c

I am building a module which connects to a camera, takes a picture, and reads the data into a piddle. All of this takes place in an Inline::C command. Using the procedure in the [PDL documentation](http://pdl.perl.org/?docs=API&title=PDL%3a%3aAPI#creating_a_piddle_in_c) I can create a `pdl *` and return it. However the camera could fail to take a picture in which case I would like to return `0` as per the usual covention `my $pic_pdl = $Camera->TakePicture or die "Failed to take image"`. This seems to mean that I will need to use the `Inline_Stack_Push` mechanism but I am not sure how to properly convert the `pdl *` into an `SV*`. Also I would like to, if possible, set `$!` with the error code too. Can this be done in Inline?

Comment: Did you try just returning NULL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `pdl*` is converted to an SV by code found in the typemap.

```
$ cat `perl -E'use PDL::Core::Dev; say PDL_TYPEMAP'`
TYPEMAP
pdl*    T_PDL
pdl *   T_PDL
Logical T_IV
float   T_NV

INPUT

T_PDL
        $var = PDL->SvPDLV($arg)


OUTPUT

T_PDL
        PDL->SetSV_PDL($arg,$var);
```

If I read that right, you should be able to do something like:

```
SV* my_new {
    pdl* p = NULL;

    ...

    if (error) {
        if (p)
            free(p);  /* I think */
        return &PL_sv_undef;
    } else {
        SV* rv = newSV(0);
        PDL->SetSV_PDL(rv, p);
        return rv;
    }
}
```

As for `$!`, it's simply an interface to C's `errno`. Simply set `errno`.

```
$ perl -E'use Inline C => "void f(int i) { errno = i; }"; f($ARGV[0]); say 0+$!; say $!;' 2
2
No such file or directory

$ perl -E'use Inline C => "void f(int i) { errno = i; }"; f($ARGV[0]); say 0+$!; say $!;' 3
3
No such process

$ perl -E'use Inline C => "void f(int i) { errno = i; }"; f($ARGV[0]); say 0+$!; say $!;' 4
4
Interrupted system call
```

Comment: you know, I was just looking at the typemap as you posted this. I have a feeling that you are correct. And thanks for the info on `erro` as I don't come from a C background, I didn't know that.

Comment: @Joel, [errno.h](http://linux.die.net/man/3/errno) provides portable constants (such as EACCES for permission denied) you can use to set `errno`.